# Link attribute not getting printed in BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, urllib

I am coding a program that will get pull the top news headlines from google news. It is supposed to be printing the headline and the link for the article. But, it wont print the link.

```py
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

news_url="https://news.google.com/news/rss"
Client=urlopen(news_url)
xml_page=Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_page=soup(xml_page,"lxml")
news_list=soup_page.findAll("item")
# Print news title, url and publish date
for news in news_list:
  print(news.title.text)
  print(news.link.text)  
  print("-"*10)
```

This is an example of an output line

```py
Following Falcon 9 Saturday launch, CRS-17 Dragon arrives at the ISS

----------
```

it is supposed to print the headline and the link. but it is only printing the headline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This html has a strange structure, but if you change the `for` loop in your code to this:

```
for news in news_list:
   link = news.select_one('title')    
   print(link.text)
   print(link.next_sibling.next_sibling)
   print("-"*10)
```

You should get the headline with the link.

Comment: Ok so this looks very promising, instead of printing a link it prints this ```<guid isPermaLink="false">52780287444614</guid>``` I dont know if i should just leave the link out of it.

Comment: @MADScienceBdukester10 - I don't know why you get this; I just tried it in a different computer and IDE, and the 1st result is `WH instructs former counsel not to comply with congressional subpoena - ABC News
https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/white-house-instruct-counsel-comply-congressional-subpoena/story?id=62873987`

Comment: Strange, could it be a module that I do not have on my computer?

Comment: Figured it out. For some reason I had a second version of the file that was using xml  instead on lxml. When I ran it again using lxml, it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: @MADScienceBdukester10 Glad it worked out at the end!

Comment: Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should modify this line in your code:

```
soup_page=soup(xml_page,"lxml")
```

into:

```
soup_page=soup(xml_page,"xml")
```

and you get the result.

Comment: What do you mean by _xml does not work on my computer for some reason_?